# How to get value from Custom field Opencart Database?

Tags: php, oop, opencart

I developed the OpenCart module. I intend to add the receipt number on each product to add field **"nota"** in **"oc_product"** table. The plan when users place an order, then any goods ordered will get a receipt number when you are on the "View Cart"

I've been following the rules of how to add custom fields in OpenCart and get the value of the field **"nota"** extension such as this:

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=2838

but it appears an error in `index.php?route=checkout/cart`

```
Notice: Undefined index: nota in D:\DATA PENTING\Project\Proyek\htdocs\toko\catalog\controller\checkout\cart.php on line 276
```

This error only when in the "View Cart", if the other page like `index.php?route=product/product&product_id=*` no error occurs and showing receipt number.

and if i follow error i found this codes and then add codes to get "nota" value, but still error occurs.

```
$this->data['products'][] = array(
                    'key'                 => $product['key'],
                    'thumb'               => $image,
                    'name'                => $product['name'],
                    'model'               => $product['model'],
                    'nota'                => $product['nota'],
                    'option'              => $option_data,
                    'quantity'            => $product['quantity'],
                    'stock'               => $product['stock'] ? true : !(!$this->config->get('config_stock_checkout') || $this->config->get('config_stock_warning')),
                    'reward'              => ($product['reward'] ? sprintf($this->language->get('text_points'), $product['reward']) : ''),
                    'price'               => $price,
                    'total'               => $total,
                    'href'                => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id']),
                    'remove'              => $this->url->link('checkout/cart', 'remove=' . $product['key']),
                    'recurring'           => $product['recurring'],
                    'profile_name'        => $product['profile_name'],
                    'profile_description' => $profile_description,
                );
            }
```

Anyone can help this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please edit system/library/cart.php

after this line :

> 'name'            => $product_query->row['name'],

add:

> 'nota'            => $product_query->row['nota'],